# pandasでエクセル読み込み時のエラーの解決方法を教えてください

Tags: python, python3, pandas, openpyxl

pandasでエクセル(xlsx)を読み込んでcsvファイルを書き出す、というプログラムを作っています。
pandasでエクセルファイル読み込み時にエラーがでるようで、それについて調べてみると `pip install xlrd` で解決、ということでしたがインストールしても解決しません。

コマンドプロンプトを開いて `python test.py` でプログラムは動きます。
しかし、test.pyをダブルクリックしても動いてくれません。
他のpyプログラムはダブルクリックで動いてくれます。

exe化しても動いてくれません。その際のエラーは以下の通りです。

```
Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'.Install xlrd>=1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

どなたか分かる方教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name=0, index_col=0)
df.to_csv('item.csv', header=True, index=False, encoding="shift-jis")
```

読み込む sample.xlsx は以下のように簡単なものです。

```
A B C
one 11 12 13
two 21 22 23
three 31 32 33
```

#### その他に試したこと

①pip install xlrd==1.2.0
xlrdのバージョンを下げても駄目でした。

②pip install openpyxlインストールして
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx',engine="openpyxl")
Excel読み取り時にライブラリを指定しても駄目でした。

Python 3.10
Windows 10

コマンドプロンプト `pip list` で以下のバージョンが入っています。
xlrd 2.0.1
pip 21.2.4
pandas 1.4.2
openpyxl 3.0.9

Comment: 「コマンドプロンプトを開いて実行すると動きます」とありますが、これはエクセルの読み込みも問題無いという事ですか？ (ダブルクリックで起動した場合のみ、問題が発生している？)

Comment: 試しにスクリプトファイル名を`test.py`から`sample.py`等に変えてみるとか。[Pythonでtest.pyを作るな！](https://qiita.com/msmhrt/items/7e2a335a4c64bcc6e044) 同類で今探しても見つからないのですが、pandasかxlrdで使われているらしい`copy.py`というファイルと同名の独自ファイルがあって失敗したという記事を見たことがあります。それからexe化して失敗するのは、スクリプト上で明示的に`import xlrd`しておくとか、PyInstallerなら[--hidden-import](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=hidden#cmdoption-hidden-import)で指定してみるとかを試してみてはどうでしょう？ [PyInstallerでPythonがないWindows環境で動作するexeファイルを作成する](https://qiita.com/bwtakacy/items/51b765b4da77a76d6f32), [Understanding PyInstaller Hooks](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html)

Comment: Pythonのバージョンを下げてみることはご検討されましたか．

Comment: cubickさん、sauさん、コメントありがとうございます。

Python 3.10をアップロードして使ったのですが、一旦PythonをすべてアンインストールしてPython3.7をインストールして試したところ実行することができました。
今回は恐らくですが、Pythonのバージョンとライブラリのバージョンを合わす必要があったのかな、と思います。
Anacondaも入れていたのでそっちの方のpythonの問題かも知れないと色々と原因を探っていたので解決するのに時間が掛かりましたがpython環境の勉強になりました。